# Is this things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu script safe?

Tags: software-installation

I am going to install Ubuntu 12.04, and I wonder if I should trust/run the .sh script proposed on this site: [Things to do after Installing Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin#.UlKp2d0kX1E).

By the way, do I need to anything in particular after installing Ubuntu?

Comment: As a rule of thumb you should never run a script you don't understand or copy and paste something directly from an untrusted web page into a shell, especially a root shell! It could be something entirely different from what appears on the web page and therefore execute arbitrary command. http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1bv54e/dont_copypaste_from_website_to_terminal_crosspost/

Answer (score 2):

In fact you will learn a lot more if you do the steps one-by-one, rather than just run the .sh script. This also has the advantage that you can check whether the proposed software is still being maintained. To give but one example: today one would no longer advise to install Firestarter.

Also, as a general rule you should not trust the internet.

Comment: Don't trust this comment (I **love** paradoxes :)... and smilies within brackets :) )

Answer (score 0):

The script was originally written of elementary OS Luna, and Ubuntu 12.04. If you're running 14.04, some of those steps are downright harmful, and others simply unnecessary. Examples being:

## Harmful:

- Using `precise` repositories in`/etc/apt/sources.list` - use `trusty` if you have to muck around in there. Or the Software Sources GUI.
- Deleting the backup of the `sources.list` (what sort of guide does that?)

## Unnecessary:

- Adding PPAs for GIMP, GNOME3 and VLC. All three are in very good shape in Ubuntu 14.04, with no reason for an average user to go gunning after PPAs.
- Adding PPAs for Java. Java 7 is available for Ubuntu 14.04.
- Getting `libdvdcss` from the VLC repository (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/487956/158442)).
- Installing `flashplugin-installer` - I suggest `adobe-flashplugin` instead, which comes as a single package instead of downloading extra stuff from the internet.

Lastly, if you do install Google Chrome from the command line using the commands from that page, be sure to run `sudo apt-get install -f` after.