# Ubuntu 14.04 and libdvdcss file

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't get it to recognize Libdvdcss2, which is downloaded to the download file.  There I clicked on the bz2 file and it opened to give me a nice neat package that doesn't work.  What do I need to do or try.  Keep in mind I am a newbie.

Answer (score 10):

From [help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

By installing the libdvdcss2 package you can play
encrypted DVDs with:

1. Kaffeine , the Kubuntu video player
2. MPlayer
3. xine
4. Totem-xine
5. VLC media player
6. Ogle
7. XBMC Media Center

12.04 onwards works this way.

Install the libdvdread4 package ( no need to add third party repositories ) via Synaptic or command line: (note: if you have installed *ubuntu-restricted-extras this has already been installed automatically for you)

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

Then open a terminal window and execute:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Rebooting may be necessary.

After this, VLC will automatically use it.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to write "thanks" messages on the site, but in this case I just can't help it. Thank you for "sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh" - now I can finally watch some DVDs!

Comment: There is a [gigantic security flaw](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdvdread/+bug/1317386) in `install-css.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't provide libdvdcss in repositories so you need to add vlc ppa to the sources.list so you can download it.

```
 sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
 curl ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/videolan-apt.asc | sudo apt-key add -
 echo "deb ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download libdvdcss too by navigating to the appropriate section, eg; for trusty:
ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/debian/trusty

Answer (score -1):

Before you install:

libdvdread4/install-css.sh

you BETTER read that Microsoft EULA you are agreeing to, before you execute the installation. Not to go Richard Stallman on anyone here, but when they are installing a FONT EULA, you have to ask yourself, what else are they installing?

There are other GPL offerings out there, that don't involve you giving your rights away.