# How should I install libdvdcss.so.2 (Library) to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: brasero

I'd like to make a Copy of a DVD using Brasero Disc Burner.

It says I can't do it because I haven't got libdvdcss.so.2 (Library), 
which I should install manually.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

and then

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

but the immediate output is

```
sudo: /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh: command not found
```

How should I install `libdvdcss.so.2` manually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 and libdvdcss file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/487949/ubuntu-14-04-and-libdvdcss-file)

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 they changed a way to install `libdvdcss2`.

Install it by

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

and follow on-screen directions.

Comment: Got this: TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA                                        
 │                                                                             
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE

Comment: Is it possible that it could compromise my computer?

Comment: I wrote how to accept the license. And your question about "compromise" is not clear.

Comment: Should I accept the agreement, could it compromise my computer?

Comment: Yes, accept it. Why compromise?

Comment: I cannot accept it. I press ENTER and nothing happens

Comment: To be honest, this answer suggests to install a lot more proprietary stuff than what is needed.

Comment: @NEven navigate by Tab button, then press Enter.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto The next question would be about codecs anyway ;-)

Comment: Sorry. It does work

Comment: Again: command not found

Comment: I changed the answer.