# How to install libdvdcss.so.2 (Library) to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, backup, dvd, brasero

I want to make a copy of a DVD with Brasero. But it asks for libdvdcss.so.2.

I already did what was suggested at [How should I install libdvdcss.so.2 (Library) to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819671/how-should-i-install-libdvdcss-so-2-library-to-ubuntu-16-04)

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me

**Try** (this may not be needed for Ubuntu 20.04)

```
    sudo apt install libdvdread4
```

**Do**

```
    sudo apt install libdvdnav4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg 
    sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

After that I was able to copy the DVD with brasero.

Comment: Ubuntu requires the additional command sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg after the first command above.

Comment: On Focal 20.04 it's `libdvdread7` now.

Comment: `libdvdread4` (or 7 on Focal)  is not enough. The package `libdvd-pkg` (it's included also in the first line under **Do** above, so the commands under **Do** work.

Answer (score 8):

### For Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

To do the above without user interaction, add `-y` after each `apt install` and `--frontend=noninteractive` after `pkg-reconfigure`.

Note `libdvdread4` is unavailable in Ubuntu 20.04, but seems unneeded.